# How to size an image to be 100% width of the screen, but only if <1024 px

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I would like to put an image on a website. I would like it not to be a background image, but a normal image, what I can later use for hovers and *"hover over some region, something changes on the screen"* kind of interactions.

What I would like to do is to make this image 100% width of the browsing area, but only if the screen is smaller than 1024px. If the screen is bigger, then I want the image to be exactly 1024px wide.

How would you do this? Somewhere I've read that CSS3 can do automatic background-width to fit with the browser window, but I think by using background image I cannot do interactive trick on the image later. But I've never done interactive tricks, so maybe it's possible.

*By interactive tricks I mean that if the mouse pointer is over a polygon region, then a div or an image changes or appears somewhere. Can you point me where to read about this technique, and how is it called?*

I have no experience in JavaScript, I've only used premade JS plugins, but if you say that for this problem I really should use JS then I have no problem with that.

Comment: You can look at [CSS Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use css `max-width`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/max-width

HTML:

```
<img src="flower.jpg" class="no-bigger-than-1024"/>
```

CSS:

```
.no-bigger-than-1024{width:100%; max-width:1024px;}
```

Comment: @Joseph, you're rich enough! ;)

Comment: how about +1 to both of you ;)

Comment: lol, XD but in any case this is definitely the right answer :) and a good link too.

Comment: Sorry, i've left out the most important point: have a look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034906/how-to-center-and-size-an-image-to-be-100-width-of-the-screen-but-only-if-1024

Answer (score 1):

```
img
{
    max-width:1024px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i've left out the most important point: have a look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034906/how-to-center-and-size-an-image-to-be-100-width-of-the-screen-but-only-if-1024