# How to center and size an image to be 100% width of the screen, but only if <1024 px

Tags: javascript, html, image, css

OK, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7034626/518169) was my original question, where I've left out the most important thing: to **horizontally center** the image, if the screen is bigger than max-width.

So far the classic trick for `margin: auto` doesn't work, because then `width: 100%` isn't the screen anymore.

```
#main {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1024px;
background-color: red;
}

#bigimage {
max-width: 1024px;
width: 100%;
}   


<div id="main" role="main">
    <img src="img/bigimage.jpg" id="bigimage">
</div>
```

So I'm looking for an other solution. **Any idea how to make max-width and horizontal centering work together?**

**Update:**

OK, I'm almost there:

```
#main {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

#bigimage {
max-width: 1024px;
width: 100%;
}
```

And it works great in all browsers, **except IE8.** Even IE 7 is OK! IE8 resizes the image without keeping the aspect ratio! I mean it makes it max-width wide but original width high. **Can you help me how to make it not distort in IE8?**

Also, a live site, with 500px max-width:
http://ilhaamproject.com/

Comment: Do you mean vertical centering? Or do you mean horizontal? Because you are talking about widths and not heights.

Comment: Sorry, horizontally of course, my bad!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to size an image to be 100% width of the screen, but only if <1024 px](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034626/how-to-size-an-image-to-be-100-width-of-the-screen-but-only-if-1024-px)

Comment: Its my question, I wanted to accept the answer as I asked it without the centering part. Do you think I should delete the old question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your image have an static aspect ratio then it can be done with `max-height`. If you add `max-height` to your image based on the `1024px` width (726px for 4by3 aspect ratio) then it would be fine in every browser. See the fiddle [before](http://jsfiddle.net/uk7eY/) applying max-height and [after](http://jsfiddle.net/uk7eY/1/) that. I just used 400px width instead.

HTML:

```
    <div id="container">
        <img id="bigDude" src="http://www.ladygagapic.info/wallpaper/flower-17.jpg" />
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{text-align:center; border:1px solid gray;}
#bigDude{max-width:400px; width:100%;}
```

BUT if your images are not in same size or aspect ratio you maybe need some JavaScript just like how [Facebook forced to do that](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/developing-facebooks-new-photo-viewer/499447633919).

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed! In my case it is just a single image, so it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Change your (updated) CSS to the following and it should work:

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the #bigimage img within the #main div. Since the main div is 1024px wide, the 100% will always be 1024. The result here is that you'll always see 1024px. If you remove the width attribute from #main or change it to 100%, you should start to see what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/4avax/1)

I ended up opting for `display:table-row` ... oh well :P

Comment: As soon as I put width: 1024px in main, then the max-width of img doesn't work (naturally).

Comment: @zsero well... there's a non-cross-browser way at least :(

Comment: Do you think it is needed over my updated version above? Is IE8 distorsion happening in this version too?